# Specifying Referential transparency in ACSL

Tags: frama-c, acsl

I want to find some ACSL annotation that can be applied to a function or function pointer to indicate that it has the property of referential transparency. Some way to say "this function will always return the same value when given the same arguments". So far I haven't found any such way. Can anyone point me to a way to express that?

Maybe some way to refer to an arbitrary logic function? If I could name an unknown `logic boolean uknown_function(void* a, void* b) = /* this is unkown */;` then I could document a function as having a postcondition that it's `\result` is equal to this arbitrary/unknown logic function?

The larger context is trying to do type-erased comparisons. I want to generally express the concept of "the user has given me `void*`s to work with and a `bool (*)(void const*, void const*)` to compare them with, and the user is guaranteeing to me that the function provided really is a strict partial order over whatever those pointers point to."  If I had that, then I could start to describe properties of these type-erased objects being sorted, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed no direct possibility to do that in ACSL: a function contract only specifies what happens during a single call of the function. You could indeed rely on a declared but left undefined logic function, with a `reads` clause that specifies the part of the C memory state that the function will need to compute its result, e.g.

`/*@ logic boolean unknown_function{L}(int* a, int* b) reads a[0 .. 1], b[2 .. 3]; */`

but if you work with `void *`, without knowing the size of the underlying objects, this might be tricky to specify: unless the result of `unknown_function` relies solely on the value of the pointer, and not the content of the pointed object, in which case you don't need that `reads` trick.

Note in addition that contracts over function pointers are not supported yet, which will probably be an issue for what you intend to do if I understand correctly your last paragraph.

Finally, you might be interested in an upcoming plug-in, RPP, that proposes a way to specify, prove, and use properties relating several calls of one or more C function(s). It is described [here](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/cea-01808885) and [here](https://hal-cea.archives-ouvertes.fr/cea-01835470/), and a public release should happen in a not-too-distant future.

Comment: Thank you. RPP looks exciting, and I'm looking forward to it. I was surprised to see the logic-function approach work because I'd had little success locally. But it looks like my frama-c install was a couple years old. I got a chlorine from opam and now that works like you said. I've still got a ways to go, but that looks like exactly what I want.